# Does CSR1000v on AWS support IPv6?

Tags: cisco, ipv6, mpls, aws

I'm trying to implement Segment Routing IPv6 (SRv6) in Cisco CSR1000v on AWS. I'm having issues with IPv6 which gave the impression that IPv6 data plane does not work.

Similarly, I configured a static IPv6 LAN pool on all CSR1000v I have in my region but they were not able to discover neighbor. Even static binding the Mac address did not help.

So, does anybody try IPv6 in CSR1000v on AWS? Does IPv6 data plane work in CSR1000v on AWS?

Comment: The short answer is yes.  If you provide more information on how you've configured your VPC and router we might be able to help you.  Edit your question to include the configurations using the preformatted text option {}

Comment: @RonTrunk Thanks a lot! I have solved the problem. You were right! I will write the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was creating new VPCs, I didn't enable IPv6 addressing but I found out a way to do that. The VMs that run Linux-based was able to get IPv6 addresses. However, the CSRs which are already deployed in those different VPCs were not been able to get IPv6 addresses, even though it was shown on the AWS console. I had to deploy other CSRs routers in order to get IPv6 addresses.